How to put the Debug Console under the Interactive Window in VSCode
In Visual Studio Code, I would like to move the Debug Console under the Interactive Window as indicate by the arrow in the following figure:

Note that I can easily put the Debug Console at the bottom of the whole VSCode window as follows, by right-clicking on the tab and selecting Panel position > Bottom. But this is not what I want, as it reduces the space in the code editor. Simply dragging the Debug Console with the mouse does not work either.

